# Failed Unit Test on smartcontract_lotter from Patrick C. Brownie Course

Tags: python, unit-testing, solidity, brownie

I'm going through the FreeCodeCamp/Chainlink course on Brownie/Solidity from Patrick Collins and can't debug a failed assertion in my test_can_pick_winner_correctly unit test.  I've had no issues with all the other tests and not sure if there have been minor changes between the release of the video/course.

> The assertion error I'm getting:
> assert lottery.recentWinner() == account
> E       AssertionError: assert '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3' == <Account '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871'>
> E        +  where '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3' = <ContractCall 'recentWinner()'>()
> E        +    where <ContractCall 'recentWinner()'> = <Lottery Contract '0x6951b5Bd815043E3F842c1b026b0Fa888Cc2DD85'>.recentWinner

> tests\test_lottery_unit.py:85: AssertionError

I know it's saying that the address I'm asserting is the winner doesn't match the address when I invoke the contract.  I'm stumped at where the error is coming in assuming it's something with the states changing although in the unit test (just below) I'm stating that the first entrant, account[0] should win since the STATIC_RNG has a modulo of 0 for the number of contestants (3).

This is the unit test in my test_lottery_file with the other tests removed (since they have no effect):

```
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network, exceptions
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS,
    get_account,
    fund_with_link,
    get_contract,
)
from scripts.deploy_lottery import deploy_lottery
from web3 import Web3
import pytest

def test_can_pick_winner_correctly():
    # Arrange
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        pytest.skip()
    lottery = deploy_lottery()
    account = get_account()
    lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
    lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": lottery.getEntranceFee()})
    lottery.enter({"from": get_account(index=1), "value": lottery.getEntranceFee()})
    lottery.enter({"from": get_account(index=2), "value": lottery.getEntranceFee()})
    fund_with_link(lottery)
    transaction = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
    request_id = transaction.events["RequestedRandomness"]["requestId"]
    STATIC_RNG = 777
    get_contract("vrf_coordinator").callBackWithRandomness(
        request_id, STATIC_RNG, lottery.address, {"from": account}
    )
    starting_balance_of_account = account.balance()
    balance_of_lottery = lottery.balance()
    # 777 % 3 = 0
    assert lottery.recentWinner() == account
    assert lottery.balance() == 0
    assert account.balance() == starting_balance_of_account + balance_of_lottery
```

My deploy_lottery.py file:

```
from dis import show_code

from pkg_resources import ensure_directory
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, get_contract, fund_with_link
from brownie import Lottery, network, config
import time


def deploy_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
        get_contract("eth_usd_price_feed").address,
        get_contract("vrf_coordinator").address,
        get_contract("link_token").address,
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"],
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify", False),
    )
    print("Deployed Lottery!")
    return lottery


def start_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    starting_tx = lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
    starting_tx.wait(1)
    print("The lottery has started")


def enter_lotter():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    value = lottery.getEntranceFee() + 10000000
    tx = lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": value})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("You entered the lottery!")


def end_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    # fund the contract and then end the lottery
    tx = fund_with_link(lottery.address)
    tx.wait(1)
    ending_transaction = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
    ending_transaction.wait(1)
    time.sleep(60)
    print(f"{lottery.recentWinner()} is the new winner!")


def main():
    deploy_lottery()
    start_lottery()
    enter_lotter()
    end_lottery()
```

Solidity Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, Ownable {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSED,
        CALCULATING_WINNER
    }
    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    uint256 public fee;
    bytes32 public keyhash;
    event RequestedRandomness(bytes32 requestId);
    address payable public recentWinner;
    uint256 public randomness;

    constructor(
        address _priceFeedAddress,
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        address _link,
        uint256 _fee,
        bytes32 _keyhash
    ) public VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _link) {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        fee = _fee;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * (10**10); //18 decimals
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
            "Can't start a new lottery yet!"
        );
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        emit RequestedRandomness(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER,
            "You aren't there yet!"
        );
        require(_randomness > 0, "random-not-found");
        uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomness & players.length;
        recentWinner = players[indexOfWinner];
        recentWinner.transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address payable[](0);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        randomness = _randomness;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I solved the issue it was the following line in the fulfillRandomness function in the solidity contract:
uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomness & players.length;
I needed to have the % sign instead to calculate the modulo instead of &
uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomness % players.length;